# Edittext cursor not visible in android

Tags: android

I am using custom Edittext like this

```
public class DosisEdittextFont extends TextView {
     public DosisEdittextFont(Context context) {
         super(context);
         init(context);
     }

     public DosisEdittextFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);
         init(context);
     }

     public DosisEdittextFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
         int defStyleAttr) {
         super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
         init(context);
     }

     private void init(Context context) {
         Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
             "fonts/Dosis-Regular.otf");
         this.setTypeface(t);
     }
 }
```

But because of that cursor is not showing in `EditText`. how to set cursor in custom `EditText`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may extends EditText instead of TextView

Comment: No problems dude, glad I found the problem at the first shot :p

Comment: @aj0822 please, mark as the correct answer so everyone can see which was the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
    public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        if(!isInEditMode())
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if(!isInEditMode())
        init(attrs);

    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if(!isInEditMode())
        init(null);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        if (attrs!=null) 
        {
             TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView);
             String fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomTextView_fontFamily);

             if (fontName!=null) 
             {
                 Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/"+fontName);
                 setTypeface(myTypeface);
             }
             a.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

**To Use In Your Layout**

```
 <CustomEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etEmailId"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:textColor="@color/input_text_color"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_text_color"
            customfont:fontFamily="YOUR FONT NAME.ttf"

            />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Reason for not appearance of cursor in edittext are many like your theme appearance    
i.e. theme style or edittext background and one is that you extending TextView,
so try extending EditText in place of TextView as:


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

private Context context;
private AttributeSet attrs;
private int defStyle;

public CustomEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    this.attrs = attrs;
    init();
}

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
    this.attrs = attrs;
    this.defStyle = defStyle;
    init();
}

private void init() {
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/montserrat_bold.ttf");
    this.setTypeface(font);
}

@Override
public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/montserrat_bold.ttf");
    super.setTypeface(tf, style);
}

@Override
public void setTypeface(Typeface tf) {
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/montserrat_bold.ttf");
    super.setTypeface(tf);
}
}

 and in you layout xml

<com.example.CustomEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:hint="text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"/>




 So, try replacing textview with edittext , if still not resolve, this 
 occurs due to your activity theme or your edittext background
```